# Cannot rotate on X Y Z axis at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function loop(){
  var XValue = $('#xval').val();
  var YValue = $('#yval').val();
  var ZValue = $('#zval').val();

  $('#cube').css({
    transform: 'rotateX('+XValue+'deg)',
    transform: 'rotateY('+YValue+'deg)',
    transform: 'rotateZ('+ZValue+'deg)',
  });

  setTimeout(loop,1);
}

loop();
```

I have made a 3D model inside css but i have problem rotating it using jquery. It only listens to the last command with transform in it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You are overwriting the transform property each time until you have only set the rotateZ value.

Comment: So how can I fix it ?

Comment: Both answers posted thus far have valid solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have duplicate keys in an object. At best, you're just going to overwrite the previous value, not add to it. Join your rotations into a single string.

```
$('#cube').css({
  transform: 'rotateX('+XValue+'deg) rotateY('+YValue+'deg) rotateZ('+ZValue+'deg)'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i didnt know you can do it all in one line. THANKS :D

Answer (score 2):

The [`transform` style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) allows for providing multiple transforms together (note the example below `/* Multiple function values */`).

You can use this from JavaScript as well:

```
$('#cube').css({
  transform: 'rotateX('+XValue+'deg) rotateY('+YValue+'deg) rotateZ('+ZValue+'deg)'
});
```

---

As is, the object passed to `.css()` can only keep 1 of the 3 `transform` keys you're trying to provide, with results similar to:

```
var transform;
transform = 'rotateX('+XValue+'deg)';
transform = 'rotateY('+YValue+'deg)'; // rotateX is discarded
transform = 'rotateZ('+ZValue+'deg)'; // rotateY is discarded

$('#cube').css({
  transform: transform
});
```